# How to disable project migration dialogue when opening a SharePoint 2010 project?

Tags: 2010, development, 2013, visual-studio-2012

We need to develop for SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2010 concurrently, so I installed Windows Server 2012 on my machine with a SharePoint 2013 installed, because of the downward compatibility of SharePoint 2013.

When opening a solution containing SharePoint 2010 projects with Visual Studio 2012 (with the Office 2013 developer tools installed), every time I get an annoying dialogue saying:

> Do you want to upgrade "SharePoint2010Project.csproj" tp a SharePoint 2013 solution? Once the upgrade is complete, the solution can't be deployed to SharePoint 2010. Do you want to continue?

and after clicking "No", a migration report opens in my browser. Additionally, the .csproj file gets checked-out and the `FileUpgradeFlags` element gets a value of `40`.

Appart from being really annoying (especially when opening very large solutions), the check-out of the project file and value of `FileUpgradeFlags` is a problem when accidentally checked-in, because then all my collegues still working with Windows 7 and SharePoint 2010 would be presented with another migration dialogue upon opening the respective solution.

Does anyone experience a similar behaviour and possibly know a way to disable the migration dialogue and check-out of the project files?

We need the SharePoint 2010 projects to stay that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted an answer to your question on stackoverflow site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065083/disable-project-migration-dialogue-when-opening-a-sharepoint-2010-project)

The short answer - update **.csproj** file:

```
<TargetOfficeVersion>15.0</TargetOfficeVersion>
```

And commit to SVN or Git.

Then update **.csproj.user** file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <TargetOfficeVersion>14.0</TargetOfficeVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Keep this file localy on the machine with SP 2010.

Comment: Once I get enough reputation, I will upvote your answer here, too! :)